# Returning Values at Specific Positions

Tags: python, matrix

```
Returns a new matrix with the given shape, filled with the given value.
#   value is a single float or integer value used to fill the new matrix.
#   shape is a tuple (number of rows, number of columns) for the new matrix.
# This is a static method that builds the contents and calls the Matrix constructor.
def of(value, shape: tuple):
    contents = []
    for i in range(shape[0]):
        row = []
        for j in range(shape[1]):
            row.append(value)
        contents.append(row)
    return Matrix(contents)
```

Question answered! I configured the code into doing exactly what I had hoped. Using append was unfamiliar to me and after the answer I received I was able to implement it accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to iterate over anything. `key` is a tuple that contains the `i` and `j` index of the element that has been requested. You need to simply return _that item!_. Since you already know that the `i`th row is accessed as `self.contents[i]`, and the `j`th column of that row is `self.contents[i][j]`, that's all you need to return (using `%` like you have to wrap around)

Comment: `__setitem__` behaves similarly to `__getitem__`, all you'd do is replace `return self.contents[i][j]` with `self.contents[i][j] = value`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for looping. Just use the two elements of `key` as indexes.

```
def __getitem__(self, key: tuple):
    i = key[0] % self.shape[0]
    j = key[1] % self.shape[1]
    return self.contents[i][j]
```

Your code wasn't even iterating, since it returns unconditionally inside the loop. It never gets to the second loop.